# get Location with timeout

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

For save power I want to call `requestLocation()` every 30 sec for get new location.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
  self.requestLocation()
}
```

But I have a problem here. The `requestLocation()` called, `didUpdateLocations` too, but `CLLocation` did't changed all time. 
P.S. I use Freeway Drive in the simulator

```
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:00:10 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:00:40 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
<+37.42467819,-122.22918858> +/- 5.00m (speed 35.86 mps / course 311.13) @ 29.01.2018, 12:01:10 Восточная Европа, стандартное время
```

If I call only `requestLocation()` without deadline all work perfect.

Have you any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: can you post your requestLocation Code? also you have to stopUpdatingLocation when a location arrive in the `stopUpdatingLocation` delegate method

Comment: @ReinierMelian

`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  
  if let location = locations.last {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
      requestLocation()
    }
  }
}`

requestLocation() or start/stop - it's doesn't matter. results - locations didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `CLLocationManager` `startUpdatingLocation` method the `CLLocationManager` will be updating location until you call the `stopUpdatingLocation` method which stop from searching location

Assuming that your `requestLocation()` method is calling         `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` where manager is `var manager = CLLocationManager()` you need to stop requesting location when a valid locations is received by the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `didUpdateLocations` is called your code will be something like this

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userlocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    self.userLoc = userlocation
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
       self.requestLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need start update again after few second. And this is a problem. 
I start update after few sec and in `didUpdateLocations` delegate my CLLocation didn't change

Comment: do you have new CLLocation coordinate after start from `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` all time ? In Freewar Drive on sim. Case I didn't

Comment: You will stop the locationManager every time you get a valid position an restart it after 30 secs, that is what you need don't you? @ShuZik

Comment: exactly @ReinierMelian

Comment: Well that is what my answer do @ShuZik

Comment: you know... this is work... 
`manager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

This is fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: by the way I think that "Waiting between one location update and another to save battery" should be a better name for this question @ShuZik

Answer (score 0):

See this (change time parameter for your value)

```
internal func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let newLocation = locations.last
    {
        let locationAge = -newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        if locationAge > 5.0
        {
            return
        }
        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0
        {
            return
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: this don't save battery as the `CLLocationManager` will continue searching for valid location, you are dismissing some reported location only

Comment: Battery consumption more depends on accuracy than on updates. So anyway better to use this approach and select correct accuracy for locationManager.desiredAccuracy

Answer (score 0):

```
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        guard let locationManager = self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            // you have 2 choice
            // 1. requestAlwaysAuthorization
            // 2. requestWhenInUseAuthorization
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest // The accuracy of the location data
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 200 //The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.
```

So change distanceFilter on locationManager to the minimun distance will call delegate without timeout.